# WC Fields Factory Plugin minDate

Tags: woocommerce, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, uidatepicker, wc

I'm using this plugin called WC Fields Factory. I have a datePicker on my "Single product" page on woocommerce so people can book in. I am trying to disable 48 hours (minDate:2) but I can't seem to make it work. I've tried so many examples, does anyone know how to make this work?

Example: If i want to book something now (10/03/2018), the earliest I can book is 12/03/2018.

Comment: You should provide the code you have tried… Often, the problem with plugins is that you get big limitations on customizations that are not included. Please remember that *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**.*

Answer (score 0):

After going back and forward I finally figured it out.

WC Fields Factory
File Location: wc-fields-factory/includes/wcff-builder.php

Change:

```
if ("past" == $_field["disable_date"]) {
                            echo ",minDate: new Date()";
}

To:

if ("past" == $_field["disable_date"]) {
                            echo ",minDate: 2";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In wc fields factory datepicker have an option for disable next x days. So you can disable next number of days.

Before using this future make sure your wc fields factory version is 3.0.1.